# Need powershell command to detect matching line with * character to match any number of string

Tags: powershell

Below command will find partial matching line from a file and remove it 
Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern 'entry=67889_$d_*_0.1' -NotMatch

Command without * works fine but with * in between to match any string does not work and no output is obtained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have two problems going on here. If you have a variable `$d` then you need to write `${d}_` instead of `$d_` else since `_` is a valid variable character your variable name is seen as `$d_` As for the `*` it means any number of the proceeding character, If you want a total wildcard you can use `.*` since `.` matches any character.

Select-String -Pattern 'entry=67889_${d}_.*_0.1'

Note that also means you need to escape the `.` in `0.1` i.e.`0\.1` if you need it to match only a period character.